# Synchronizing SQL Server and Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a database in SQL Server, and want to implement an application that runs both SQL and DAX queries. For that, I installed SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) and the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) plugin. I created a Tabular Model project in Visual Studio, and I can import/load tables from SQL Server to Analysis Services, but that recreates all the tables. I need to have the data in a single place, due to two reasons (1) the database is large, and (2) whenever I update the SQL Server database that needs to be reflected in Analysis Services.

I tried the option "Add Data Source" (see below) in the Visual Studio project, but that didn't help. How to keep SQL Server and Analysis services synchronized without reloading the tables? What best practices are followed to build a data warehouse that supports both DAX and SQL?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DirectQuery mode if you don't want to import the data.

[Enable DirectQuery mode in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/enable-directquery-mode-in-ssdt?view=asallproducts-allversions)

Comment: Wouter, I need to implement a data warehouse that supports both SQL and DAX. Is it better to have all the data in SQL Server database and use DirectQuery enabled, or DirectQuery disabled and run both SQL and DAX in SSAS?

Comment: You cannot run SQL on SSAS so you'd need a SQL database anyway. DirectQuery is a good idea if your data does not fit in memory (after compression) or if you need real time data.

Comment: I need to refresh the data at end of day, but the amount of data is huge so Direct Query may be the only way to go